# How to send NSNotifications between tabs using UITabBarController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

Right now I have two tabs: 
Tab #1 Has a map and a pinned location. 
Tab #2 Has the address of the pinned location.

What I want to happen is that when I delete the pin on tab #1, the data on tab #2 should be set to nothing. However, what happens is that the information is still present on the 2nd tab even after I delete the pin.

Here is my code for tab #1:

```
@IBAction func trashButtonSelected(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Remove from NSDefaults
        // Show alertview
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are you Sure?", message: "Do you wish to delete your pinned Location?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet);
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (Action) in
            // Cancel
        }
        let deleteButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Destructive) { (Action) in
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("pinnedLocation");
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadData", object: nil);
            self.map.removeAnnotations(self.map.annotations);
            self.pinLocationButton.enabled = true;
        }
        alertController.addAction(deleteButton);
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction);
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

So I send a notification called reloadData that should reset all the data on tab #2.

here is my code for tab #2:

in my `viewDidLoad` method I have:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadData:", name: "reloadData", object: nil);
```

And then in my selector method:

```
func reloadData(notification:NSNotification) {
    smallMapView.removeAnnotations(smallMapView.annotations);
    smallMapView.showsUserLocation = true;
    let location = locationManager.location;
    let latitude = location!.coordinate.latitude;
    let longitude = location!.coordinate.longitude;
    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.001;
    let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.001;

    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta);
    let overallLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(overallLoc, span);
    self.smallMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    completeAddressPinned = "NO ADDRESS INFO"

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you tap on the second tab first (to run viewdidload and set the observer) and then tap back onto the first tab where you then delete the pin...does that then post the notification successfully? (as now the observer has been added)

Comment: It goes into the selector method for `reloadData`, but the data is still all set, which isn't making much sense...

Answer (score 2):

In your tab#2: you should add the observer on the init method not on viewDidload method :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector:#selector(self.shouldReloadFavoritPost(_:)),name:"shouldReloadFavorit",object:nil)
}
```